# error : no such device : 9fa0fdb-791f-4d74-b69f-0369315c9d1a. grub rescue>

Tags: boot

I have a Sony Viao desktop that i ran 13.04 live cd upon and worked flawlessly. installed successfully from within the live cd with the "alongside Windowns 7 option) and it prompted for a restart, which i did. then the error (title above) displayed and nothing else.

Comment: and i also can not get into my boot screen either

Comment: Edit your question to include the output executing `ls` in this grub rescue screen. You might also consider the answer given [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows).